# vim function key map no longer working after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to 20, I'm finding out that some of my vim mappings are not working while others are unaffected.

My mapping to toggle spell checking is among those mappings affected:

`map <F5> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR> :hi SpellBad cterm=underline,bold ctermfg=red ctermbg=DarkYellow <CR>`

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run `sed -n l`. Hit `Enter`. Hit `F5`. What is the output?

Comment: in terminal or from vim?

Comment: In the terminal

Comment: no output. nothing

Comment: I think F5/F6 are non-functioning on my keyboard. Thanks

Comment: @jeremysprofile Advice: `sed -n l` -> `cat -v`

Comment: @phd why do you prefer that?

Comment: @jeremysprofile Doesn't require one-letter script `l` that could be interpreted as an input file name.